# Unity app not able to login to Google Play Services, maybe due to permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, achievements

I did a little Unity game and I wanted to include on it Google Play Services with some achievements. I have created the achievements and so on. However, seems that it is not working, mainly the first point is that is not logging correctly to Google Play Services. Here you have the code I'm using:

http://s27.postimg.org/9epuz81sz/codigo_conexion.png

Then, I have noted, something suspicious, seems that the app in Google Play is not asking for Internet access (you can check it here):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marcos.spaceshooter

So I guess that somehow I must say in some place of Unity that I need this permission. Right?

But, there is also another strange point, if I look in Google Play Games. The game is not showing the Achievements. However, everything is published, you can check it in Google Play games if you download the game.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

lot of thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks that you're trying to login and then activate the plugin. That's wrong reverse order. Try placing InitializeInstance and Activate functions in Start() function before Social.localUser.Authenticated(...). If it doesn't help, please post Logcat logs.